# React js detect page reload

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, reload

Using React.js, how I can check if the whole page was reloaded?

```
if (window.performance) {
      console.info("window.performance works fine on this browser");
    }
    console.info(performance.navigation.type);
    if (performance.navigation.type == performance.navigation.TYPE_RELOAD) {
      console.info("This page is reloaded");
    } else {
      console.info("This page is not reloaded");
    }
```

The code above doesn't help, triggers every time I change the component or call any api on the same page.

Comment: You could put the current URL into a `pastURL` sessionStorage item on every page visit, and before you do that, check to see if `pastURL` matches the current URL?

Comment: @evolutionxbox
well the thing is that my pastUrl is same as currentUrl, example: www.test.com

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
onUnload(event) { 
  alert('page Refreshed')
}

componentDidMount() {
    window.onbeforeunload = function() {
        this.onUnload();
        return "";
    }.bind(this);
}
```